Use Prometheus to check if new row is inserted into Postgresql database
I have a postgresql database where I would like to monitor new rows appearing in my error_log table. I would like to use Prometheus for this. I wonder how this would work. I came up with 2 different solutions:
a) Prometheus queries the database every 30 seconds and checks if a new entry has appeared in the last minute. If it finds a row, it sends a message
b) Prometheus queries the database every 30 seconds and checks the number of records. If it is different from the previously checked number, it sends a message
Solution b) seems better to me, because a) it does not guarantee that I will always be notified (e.g. if Prometheus had a break in operation, limiting it to checking the last minute would cause me to skip some rows, and additionally, sometimes I might get 2 messages instead of 1). So will b) work? Is this consistent with the assumptions that Prometheus works with?

One additional approach, if you don't care about number of new warnings, and just theirprsence, and raw data contains timestamp, is to expose metric like timestamp of last error. But it'll come with overhead of timezone handling.

Yes, solution (b)aligns better with Prometheus' design principles. Prometheus works by scraping metrics at regular intervals and storing time-series data. By tracking the total number of rows in the table and comparing it with the previous scrape, you can detect changes reliably. Ensure you expose the row count as a metric via a custom exporter or a monitoring tool compatible with Prometheus (e.g., PostgreSQL Exporter). This method avoids data gaps or duplicate notifications during Prometheus downtime and ensures consistency with its pull-based model.

So it would work by comparing new value with value from last 1 minute. But what if Prometheus was down for a while and there is no new value added 1 minute ago? What I would like to achieve is compare new value with last value, rather that relaying on time

@dafie, this come to how you'll handle counter inside alert. For example you can use irate with sufficiently large interval, to accommodate any possibility of Prometheus being down.

But in terms of approach for exposition - GenZsites is right: of two described ones, counter is the preferred one.
